# error in phpMyAdmin DisplayResults.php#1226

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Iam trying to show all records in phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin givin warning
When I try to access on the of the tables in my database on PHPMyAdmin, it seems to crash PHPMyAdmin alltogether.

I can't find solutions online and I ask for your help

I have a problem that I can't solve, error **Notice in ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1226**

```
    Notice in ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1226
 Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Backtrace

./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1346: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeadersForColumns(
array,
array,
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_options` ',
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#4424: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeaders(
array,
array,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_options` ',
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1686: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1980: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
string '137',
integer 25,
NULL,
,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2199: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
,
array,
string 'dbcc',
string 'wp_options',
NULL,
NULL,
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string '137',
integer 25,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_options`',
NULL,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'dbcc',
string 'wp_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'dbcc',
string 'wp_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin?  You should make sure that you are running the latest version.

Comment: the latest 4.9.2

Comment: Are you using PHP 7.4?  If so, [see here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/b89c17c7d71ce7dc143a7720e62671ff1cf741ba).  You may  need to pull a 5.0 version from [the downloads page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).

Answer (score 21):

**I resolved with this**

In file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php, on line 1233:

```
list($order_link, $sorted_header_html)
    = $this->_getOrderLinkAndSortedHeaderHtml(
        $fields_meta[$i], $sort_expression,
        $sort_expression_nodirection, $i, $unsorted_sql_query,
        $session_max_rows, $comments,
        $sort_direction, $col_visib,
        $col_visib[$j]
    );
```

I've inserted a new validation of "isset" like:

```
$check = (isset($col_visib[$j])) ? $col_visib[$j] : false;
```

But using in the condition..

```
list($order_link, $sorted_header_html)
    = $this->_getOrderLinkAndSortedHeaderHtml(
        $fields_meta[$i], $sort_expression,
        $sort_expression_nodirection, $i, $unsorted_sql_query,
        $session_max_rows, $comments,
        $sort_direction, $col_visib,
        isset($col_visib[$j]) ? $col_visib[$j] : false
    );
```

@edit
Using php higher than 7.2. We can change

```
isset($col_visib[$j]) ? $col_visib[$j] : false
```

for

```
col_visib[$j] ?? false
```

then..

```
list($order_link, $sorted_header_html)
    = $this->_getOrderLinkAndSortedHeaderHtml(
        $fields_meta[$i], $sort_expression,
        $sort_expression_nodirection, $i, $unsorted_sql_query,
        $session_max_rows, $comments,
        $sort_direction, $col_visib,
        $col_visib[$j] ?? false
    );
```

Comment: `in my code` - thank you, was helpful, I almost shed a tear
`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php`

Comment: It seems to be sometimes at `libraries/classes/Display/Results.php` (mostly when installed with zip file in custom folder)

Answer (score 14):

I have also faced the same notice after upgrading `php` **7.2** to **7.4** on `phpmyadmin` **4.6**

Below steps solved my issue.

1. Install **PPA** by hiting `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa`  [Check the issue here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15800#issuecomment-575010567)
2. Then run `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`
3. Finally restart your apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Now i am running `phpmyadmin` **4.9.5deb2** and notice gone

Comment: I am using php 7.4 on ubuntu 18.04. I got the same issue, and it has worked for me. 
My phpmyadmin server version: 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: it broke all the application that was there on server.

Comment: Worked for me twice, 2 years apart :)

Answer (score 3):

I have upgraded php `7.2` to `7.4` and the problem with phpMyAdmin still on the same error.

The best option for me was, go to a official website:

```
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
```

Download the lastest version, so after I went to `/var/www/html` where my phpMyAdmin is placed and I copy from `~/Downloads` my latest version unzip as bellow:

> sudo cp ~/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-5.0.4-all-languages.zip .

To assure that I had the old version I changed the name of old version

> sudo mv phpMyAdmin oldphpMyAdmin

So then I unzip the new version

> sudo unzip phpMyAdmin-5.0.4-all-languages.zip

After Unzip I renamed to phpMyAdmin like before

> mv phpMyAdmin-5.0.4-all-languages phpMyAdmin

I tested on Browser, everything works fine. After I deleted the oldversion

> sudo rm -rf oldphpMyAdmin

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS